# First order second degree differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following Initial Value Problem:
$$ (\frac{dy}{dx})^2=1  \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space and \space\space y(0)=0 $$ 
It can be solved as:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=±1$$
$$y=x-a \space\space\space\space\space or \space\space\space\space y=-x-b$$
where a and b are constants of integration

substituting $y(0)=0$, we get,
$$y=±x$$
So, we are getting two solutions for this IVP. As the question is a first order differential equation, According to uniqueness theorem, We should have a unique solution for this IVP.
Does this mean that uniqueness theorem fails to apply in case of higher degree differential equations ?

Comment: i got $$y(x)=\pm x$$

Comment: Your equation is not in the right form for applying Picard-Lindelöff. After taking the square root you can apply it for the two differen ODE’s.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the Uniqueness Theorem fails, is essentially because both $y=x$ and $y=-x$ are solutions to your DFQ with given initial value.  The problem is that these integral curves intersect (slopes are different) each other (at Origin) and that is a problem. In order to apply the Uniqueness Theorem, each point must lie uniquely on an integral curve and you can't have the said above case of intersection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please give me the name of the book or link to website which contains the above explanation. I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Well, I just happen to know it from my  good old notes, but this is the closest google gave me, hope it helps....https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/geometric-methods/MIT18_03SCF11_s2_3text.pdf